# How to add in or concatenate a a value in another value in a column?

Tags: sql, join, concatenation

Ok, it maybe confusing but here's what I got:

columnX has example values 1001,1002,1003,1004 etc.

I want to update those values and add in, lets say for example 9991001, 9991002, 9991003 so on and so on.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like adding prefix?!
If so,

```
UPDATE TABLEX
SET COLX='999'+COLX
```

Assume COLX is char.
If integer, then try

```
UPDATE TABLEX
SET COLX=CAST(('999'+CAST(COLX AS VARCHAR(20))) AS INT)
```

Comment: If ColX is not a char datatype, but is instead an integer, you may need to say `SET ColumnX = '999' + CAST(ColumnX AS VARCHAR(10))`